# Kubuntu 18.10, Discover uninstalled dolphin and okular during update but can't reinstall through Discover or Terminal

Tags: package-management, updates, kubuntu, kde, dolphin

I am fairly new to Linux/Ubuntu and might be making a naive mistake but I recently installed Kubuntu 18.10 and updated all the packages from discover. On clicking update, it asked me if it could remove some packages(including dolphin and okular):

[image: Packages to be removed]

I agreed thinking there might be a new version for those but after the update, they were completely gone. I don't care about others but dolphin is a must for me. I tried to install it from Discover but Discover said it couldn't be installed due to dependency issues. So, I tried using terminal and did the Following steps:

[image: Terminal Screenshot 1]

[image: Terminal Screenshot 2]

Since, I was unable to install both ways and had a fresh install, I reinstalled kubuntu and this time again discover asked to remove these packages. I updated those packages which didn't require these packages to be removed and I am left with these 2:

[image: Remaining Packages]

These packages prompt to uninstall dolphin and some other packages before update. Any solution for this?

Comment: I did nothing, update by discover suggested that. "sudo apt full-upgrade" detected these two updates but didn't update them. And sorry for the terminal screenshot,I didn't have them in plaintext.

Comment: Yes it was a clean install, twice. I understand your suggestion to avoid Discover but even from terminal as I told above, it avoided installation of those two packages(said these  packages not installed).
Also recently I tried from discover again an this time the packages upgraded without any hassle but Discover update daemon kept crashing. I am starting to feel why you discourage discover so much.

Comment: Re. Discover, see this comment from someone who is very closely associated with KDE: https://www.reddit.com/r/kde/comments/a5i4n7/eleven_months_after_kde_talks_about_polishing/ebn7vsu. The advantage of using the terminal is that you can copy/paste the highly informative terminal output here or, if it's too long, to pastebin. And pasting code/text, let's people quote relevant stuff when they're trying to help you.

Comment: Yeah, I understood why you disliked discover and I experienced it on kubuntu(the article is on point). And I can now say that I have the same opinion. I switched to KDE neon though. 
I also understood your suggestion to paste text from terminal, I would have done it but I just had the screenshots t the time, I would take try to post text from now on.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP has mentioned in comment that he has given up and installed Neon.